# Contact form not working on customers site but works on my site?

Tags: forms

can anyone please tell me why the contact form doesnt work on this site:

www.lederduefternoget.dk  (DanDomain hosting)

it works on my site which is on another hosting company:

www.okten.dk/benny    (one.com hosting)

thanks!

Comment: It seems a bit "harsh" to ask people to check whether a contact form works. Won't they be spammed?

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to be harsh. im just new to coding and i tried everything i can. i was hoping someone had an answer to my prayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `contact_form/contact_process.php` on the first site.

Also appears the site is not running php.

Comment: ok thanks. im really really new, so what am i supposed to do from here? the contact php is there but it seems like it cant find it :(

Comment: Well, Netcraft is reporting - http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.lederduefternoget.dk/ -  that site is running Windows server and no php is listed. I'd make sure that you're putting the site on something that has php running. Your other site is running linux with php - http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.okten.dk%2F -  Contact the provider?

Comment: thanks alot! i knew there was something wrong with the server or something. ill just redirect the site for now.